# deploy scalatra app on heroku error plugin not found

Tags: eclipse, scala, heroku, xsbt-web-plugin, scalatra-sbt

I followed the guide of deploying a Scalatra app on Heroku [lien] http://www.scalatra.org/guides/deployment/heroku.html#toc_177  and I get the following error:

```
  > [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: >com.typesafe.startscript#xsbt-start-script-plugin;0.5.3: not found
```

My version of SBT is 0.13.0..

For information I'm debutante with scalatra and sbt,Please can you help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned your sbt version is 0.13.0 so:

on https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script

there are instructions for 0.13.0 version. So we need to:

1. Use 
   `com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*` instead of `com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*` in `build.scala` and
2. In `project/plugins.sbt` we need to add  start script plugin like `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")` instead of `ddSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")`

And as a bonus: don’t forget to change servlet name in `src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala` to one you have e.g. `com.blog.BlogServlet` instead of one in tutorial `com.example.app.MyScalatraServlet`

Comment: thank you very much for the reply but I have already migrated to sbt Version 0.12.0 and is functional...                                 but I'll try your solution :)